# Weak convergence with uniformly convergent functions.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Suppose $F_n$ are a sequence of distribution functions with the property that for any measurable $g$ , we neccesarily have that $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} g \; dF_n \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} g \; dF   $$

Note that $dF_n$ implies the induced probability measure.

Let $h_n$ now be a specific sequence of functions. Assume in addition to the above that the following is true $$ \sup_{x} |F_n(x) - F(x)   | \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} 0 \\ \sup_x|h_n(x) - h(x)| \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} 0   $$

Is it neccesarily true that , $$  \int_{\mathbb{R}} x h_n \; d F_n \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} x h \; dF    $$

Note : Feel free to assume standard integrability. i,e , $$  \int_{\mathbb{R}} |xh_n|  \; dF_n < \infty \; \; \; , \int_{\mathbb{R}} |x h| \; dF < \infty \; \; ,\int_{\mathbb{R}} |x| \; dF < \infty  \; , \; \int_{\mathbb{R}} |x| \; dF_n < \infty $$

The claim seems like it should be true although I am finding it hard to complete a proof of this because of the non compactness of $\mathbb{R}$ which is giving me trouble in bounding some values.

Comment: Do Is the convergence $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g \; dF_n \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} g \; dF$ suppose to hold for bounded measurable functions? If $\sup_n\int_{\mathbb R}|x|\mathrm dF_n$ is finite, then the result would reduce (using the uniform convergence) to the case where $h_n=h$ for each $n$.

Comment: It holds for any measurable $g$ , so its a bit stronger then weak convergence. However you cannot assume the sup of the integrals is finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start from 
$$\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}} x h_n \mathrm d F_n-\int_{\mathbb{R}} x h \mathrm d F \right|\leqslant \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}} x\left(h_n-h\right) \mathrm d F_n\right|+
\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}} x h \mathrm d F_n-\int_{\mathbb{R}} x h \mathrm d F \right|.$$
The first term of the right hand side does not exceed $$\int_{\mathbb R}\left|x\right|\mathrm dF_n\cdot \sup_{t\in\mathbb R} \left|h_n(t)-h(t)\right|.$$
Assuming that the convergence $$\tag{*}\int_{\mathbb{R}} g \; dF_n \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} g \; dF$$ holds for any $g$ such that $\left|g(x)\right|\leqslant C\left|x\right|$, we reduce the problem to the case $h_n=h$ for each $n$, which can be handled by $(*)$, provided that $x\mapsto xh(x)$ belongs to the class of functions $g$ such that $(*)$ holds.